# SAS 9.3 ERROR: The Enhanced Editor Control is not installed.

Tags: sas

I recently installed windows 8.1 on my virtual machine. My SAS version is 9.3.
I have a 64 Bit system, x64 based processor on my Windows 8.1
I checked this link which tells me that enhanced editor on SAS 9.3 is not supported on Windows 8/8.1 (excluding Pro or Enterprise).
http://support.sas.com/kb/44/495.html
And this link tells me which SAS components go with each respective Windows Edition:
http://support.sas.com/supportos/list

Is there a way around this ? Using SAS without the enhanced editor is like playing with a fetus instead of a child (Apologies if anyone is offended, This situation disturbs me a lot)

Comment: Have you tried some of the solutions on this site: http://support.sas.com/kb/44/495.html

Comment: They didn't have any for Windows 8.1 64bit version.

Comment: That doesn't necessary mean that it wouldn't work.

Comment: I finally got it fixed by installing the same SAS disc on windows 8.1 'Professional'. Thanks a lot for your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS has not supported 'Home' versions since Windows XP; while Win7 Home was capable of running SAS, it isn't officially supported either.

You may be able to get Enterprise Guide working; in my Pro 8.1 installation I ran into the same error, and never got the EE working but did get EG working.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to upgrade SAS to release 9.4; it's a free upgrade. And BTW, they just released the first maintenance version (9.4M1), so be sure to get that.

Comment: That won't help either. If you see http://support.sas.com/supportos/list , It still won't support enhanced editor, like windows 8 pro/enterprise do. So I think I would have to get either one of those. My main concern was whether I could do something with the existing version that could solve this issue.

Comment: Yeah, 9.4 is not going to be any better with Win8 Home.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using operating systems inside a virtual machine, couldn't you just boot up another version of Windows in your virtual machine(e.g. Windows 7) that is compatible with SAS? From my understanding of virtualization, you can run multiple different operating systems at the same time. It's the whole point of virtualization.